# Map.containsValue() is returning false when value is is in the map

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm trying to check when a value is in the map, but I don't know why `containsValue()` isn't checking it correctly.

Here's my code:

```
    Map<String, String> usersMap = userAPI.getBuyersFromBUUPToRootMap(getParentBusinessUnitId());
    //usersMap's [STDOUT] {super, root (rootSuper) - [EZMRootCmp]=3008, user, buyer A (buyer1) - [EZMBuyer]=1007, user, Obsvr (observer) - [EZMBuyer]=1006, user, Root (rootTest) - [EZMRootCmp]=3001, user, Test (test) - [EZMBuyer]=1001, zabuhab, Miguel (buyerAdmin1) - [EZMBuyer]=1008}

    System.out.println(usersMap.values()); 
    //[STDOUT] [3008, 1007, 1006, 3001, 1001, 1008]

    System.out.println(usersMap.containsValue(getUserProfile().getUserId())); //[STDOUT] false
    //getUserProfile().getUserId() [STDOUT] 1008
```

As you can see, `getUserProfile().getUserId()`, whose value is `1008` is in the Map, but it returns `false`.

Do you know why it's happening and how can I fix this situation?
I tried to add a `Long.valueOf(getUserProfile().getUserId())`; but it keeps returning `false`

PS: I searched in SO in questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538011/hashmap-containsvalue-whats-the-point), but It didn't help me for this situation

**Below, my full code:**

```
    UserAPI userAPI = ServiceLocator.getService(UserAPI.class);
    Map<String, String> usersMap = userAPI.getBuyersFromBUUPToRootMap(getParentBusinessUnitId());
    System.out.println(usersMap);
    System.out.println("#######################");
    System.out.println(usersMap.values());
    System.out.println("##########valor para getAuctionHeaderDO().getPrimaryContact().getId() #############");
    System.out.println(usersMap.containsValue(getAuctionHeaderDO().getPrimaryContact().getId()));
    System.out.println("##########valor para getUserProfile().getUserId()#############");
    System.out.println(getUserProfile().getUserId());
    System.out.println(usersMap.containsValue(getUserProfile().getUserId()));
```

**And the result:**

```
[STDOUT] {super, root (rootSuper) - [EZMRootCmp]=3008, user, buyer A (buyer1) - [EZMBuyer]=1007, user, Obsvr (observer) - [EZMBuyer]=1006, user, Root (rootTest) - [EZMRootCmp]=3001, user, Test (test) - [EZMBuyer]=1001, zabuhab, Miguel (buyerAdmin1) - [EZMBuyer]=1008}

[STDOUT] #######################

[STDOUT] [3008, 1007, 1006, 3001, 1001, 1008]

[STDOUT] ##########valor para getAuctionHeaderDO().getPrimaryContact().getId() #############

[STDOUT] false

[STDOUT] ##########valor para getUserProfile().getUserId()#############

[STDOUT] 1008

[STDOUT] false
```

Comment: did you override `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` correctly?

Comment: What datatype does `getUserProfile().getUserId()` return?

Comment: What's the return type of `getUserId()`? Is it `int` by any chance?

Comment: `Long` 1008 is not equal to `String` 1008. Hence you get false

Comment: I'll cast it to String and check it now... (I was used to code in Php, so I'm always having these casting problems).. I hope it works

Comment: FYI: it worked. I converted into String and it's working correctly now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`usersMap<String,String>` is a map of String key and String value. And I think `getAuctionHeaderDO().getPrimaryContact().getId()` return `integer` or `long`. `Map#containsValue(Object)` accepts any `object` value but could not able to find it because values are not available in same type.

---

A small derivation -

```
Map<String,String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("10", "1000");
map.put("11", "1001");
map.put("12", "1002");
map.put("13", "1003");
System.out.println(map.containsValue(1002));
```

It prints `false`.

---

You should find the value as String, then you will able to get the desired result.

```
System.out.println(map.containsValue(String.valueOf(1002)));
```

It will print `true`.

Comment: the problem isn't with getprimaryContact().getId()... the problem is when checking the getUserProfile().getUserId()... it returns a Long... I tried to cast it, but it keeps returning false

Comment: getAuctionHeaderDO().getPrimaryContact().getId() //[STDOUT] 10000 which is not in the values list, so it must return false

Comment: @periback2 Convert your `Long` to `String`

Comment: I'll try to cast to String so... brb

Comment: Don't cast, try with [String.valueOf(long value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28long%29)

Comment: yes.. this is what I meant... I thought I could call it as a casting (Idk the difference betweend doing something like (string)* something OR String.valueOf(something)..

Comment: Thanks guys! that was exactly the problem. After converting it to string it's comparing it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Your map is declared as

```
Map<String, String> usersMap = ...;
```

so the value must be a `String`. Then, I guess `getUserProfile().getUserId()` returns an `Integer` or an `int`. Try to build a `String` from this value and check the `contains` method again.